# Swagger Editor remove value input field

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Is there a way to remove the input field below `value`?  I would like to keep `(required)`

[image]

I am not using using the `Try Out` button either.  It would be nice to get rid of it as well; however, I am not seeing the option in the `JSON`.

**UPDATE**

I tried the following code, but no avail:

```
     "paths": {
    "/login": {
        "post": {
            "summary": "Test",
            "description": "Test API.",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "email",
                    "supportedSubmitMethods": [],
                    "in": "body",
                    "description": "email address",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "email address"
                },
```

Not sure if that's the right place to put `supportedSubmitMethods`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this Swagger-ui discussion on the subject [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/156), which references the following [Swagger ui parameters](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#parameters).

You could use `supportedSubmitMethods` empty array to disable the **Try it out** functionality, but this does not remove it from the page:

> An array of the HTTP operations that will have the 'Try it out!'
>   option. An empty array disables all operations. This does not filter
>   the operations from the display

To remove it from DOM, you could add some JS to place the textarea with text, and remove the **try it out** button.

You can also just use `display: none` on the CSS class "submit" (used on all **try it out** buttons).

Comment: Thanks!  I updated my question.  I tried `supportedSubmitMethods` but it's not working.  I am sure I am doing something wrong.